# Xcode 10.2 - Use of undeclared type Result

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, xcode10.2

I have downloaded Xcode 10.2 beta release. I am trying to use [new Result type](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0235-add-result.md) in Application project or Playground with Swift 5 enabled.

My code is as below:

```
import UIKit

enum SampleError: Error {
    case foo
}

func bar() -> Result<Int, SampleError> {

}
```

When compiling I am getting:

> Use of undeclared type 'Result'

I have double checked settings and verified with below code that I am using Swift 5.0

```
    #if swift(>=5.0)
    print("Hello, Swift 5.0")
    #endif
```

Does anybody encountered similar issue?

Comment: Where is `Result` declared? The compiler says it's not declared at all.

Comment: @vadian As it was [added to the stdlib "in Swift 5"](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0235-add-result.md), karmel seems to be expecting it to be declared there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

`Result` is now available with Xcode 10.2 beta 2 release. Yay

Here is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_beta_2_release_notes/swift_5_release_notes_for_xcode_10_2_beta_2) to release note where you can find more details about `Swift` changes.

Comment: Ouch, I missed that! Good point! I was so excited after reading all those articles that I thought it will be available with that release and missed checking the notes. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, since 10.2 beta2 was released, your link now redirects to beta2 release notes page, which does mention `Result` type. @karmel, I think you can download beta2 and try your code again there.